# How do I save/export an OpenGL surface into Quicktime in Cocoa/Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

i've modified the quartz composer slideshow sample from xcode to render a high speed slide show using a custom transition.

The sample uses OpenGL (Cocoa) to render the slide show.
I would like to export this slideshow into a video.

Is there a way to use Cocoa/OpenGL to output this scene into a quicktime video?

OR, should I just reimplement the SlideShow sample in Quartz composer and use it's export to Quicktime functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Cocoa supports rendering to QuickTime video directly, and I know for a fact that OpenGL itself does not.

From what I found, Apple recommends you use Quartz Composer for rendering. Here's [a link](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/QuartzOpenGL/QuartzOpenGL.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH211-SW11) to a breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

check the sample-code in /Developer/Examples/Quartz Composer/Applications/QCTV for code that does exactly what you want.

i believe that in previous versions of osx, the sample-code was called Quartz Composer TV